# svn: No worthy mechs found

Tags: svn

I've setup svnserve.  Sasl is set to false.  When I try and connect I get:

svn: No worthy mechs found

Any ideas?  Google searches aren't helping me out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a cyrus-sasl plugin that svn wants to see. On my system I installed cyrus-sasl-md5 and now I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Reason: hard disk free space = 0%